# Error in the return of the intersection points

Tags: java, geometry

My algorithm checks the relative position between two lines at this point I'm sure the lines are concurrents and want to return the point of intersection. I'm using this formula to not have linear systems:
[image]

My problem is when the input lines are as follows:
r: X= (8,1,9) + λ(2,-1,3) 
s: X (3,-4,4) + µ(1,-2,2) 
I hope the output is (-2, 6, -6) but is (7.6, 1.2, 8.4). 
Does anyone have any idea why this occurs?

My method

```
public Point3D intersectingLines(Line lineOne, Line lineTwo) {
        double x = lineOne.getPoint().getX() - lineTwo.getPoint().getX();
        double y = lineOne.getPoint().getY() - lineTwo.getPoint().getY();
        double z = lineOne.getPoint().getZ() - lineTwo.getPoint().getZ();
        Vector3D pointsDifference = new Vector3D(x, y, z);
        Vector3D second = pointsDifference.crossProduct(lineTwo.getVector());
        Vector3D first = lineOne.getVector().crossProduct(lineTwo.getVector());

        double lambda = first.getNorm() / second.getNorm();
        double xIntersectionOne = lineOne.getPoint().getX() + (lambda * lineOne.getVector().getX());
        double yIntersectionOne = lineOne.getPoint().getY() + (lambda * lineOne.getVector().getY());
        double zIntersectionOne = lineOne.getPoint().getZ() + (lambda * lineOne.getVector().getZ());

        double xInLineTwo = (xIntersectionOne - lineTwo.getPoint().getX()) / lineTwo.getVector().getX();
        double yInLineTwo = (yIntersectionOne - lineTwo.getPoint().getY()) / lineTwo.getVector().getY();
        double zInLineTwo = (zIntersectionOne - lineTwo.getPoint().getZ()) / lineTwo.getVector().getZ();
        //Here I check if the point is even correct or lambda must be negative to obtain the correct point
        if (xInLineTwo == yInLineTwo && xInLineTwo == zInLineTwo) {
            return new Point3D(xIntersectionOne, yIntersectionOne, zIntersectionOne);
        } else {
            xIntersectionOne = lineOne.getPoint().getX() + (-1 * lambda * lineOne.getVector().getX());
            yIntersectionOne = lineOne.getPoint().getY() + (-1 * lambda * lineOne.getVector().getY());
            zIntersectionOne = lineOne.getPoint().getZ() + (-1 * lambda * lineOne.getVector().getZ());

            return new Point3D(xIntersectionOne, yIntersectionOne, zIntersectionOne);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is the line `if (xInLineTwo == yInLineTwo && xInLineTwo == zInLineTwo)`. Even in the case where this condition _should_ hold, it's unlikely to hold exactly, as these are all `double` variables, not exact numbers.  You should probably apply some kind of tolerance to this condition, for example, `Math.abs(xInLineTwo - yInLineTwo) < 0.001` or something of that kind.

Comment: I also believe you would find your problem quickly if you stepped through your code with a debugger, examining the relevant variables after each step.

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with this formula to the equation in particular. Since I get only error with this equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in the equation the other tests had no difference but that particular equation yes. The equation is in "reverse" order so got lambda = |0,2| and not lambda = |5|.
[image]

And another problem was noted in the comment's David Wallace where the condition checks equality of doubles type.

[See more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385627/points-of-intersection-of-two-lines?noredirect=1#comment2822092_1385627)